# Optimization of data usage

Tags: feature-request, android-app

a breakdown of last 20 min of active usage* and 2 hours of turned off display is as follows:
51 MB foreground  **fixed**
11 MB background

This seems extremely high, as for example Gmail had 40 kB for the same duration. Even the foreground seems a bit much for (seemingly) a few snippets of text and a few avatars (that I've recently seem so they might be cached).

Can the optimization of the data transfer be looked at?
Thank you!

App v 1.0.77 stable
Android 5.0.2

*) iirc visited intro screen, cca 6 times a question list and cca 6 times an actual question, so most time was spent reading anyway

---

#### edit 1

Firstly I apologize, I swapped the fg/bg in the initial message. It still is a 62 MB of total data for a dozen of text pages over like 2 hours basically, so I think the case can still be valid...

Device is HTC One E8
Previous month I didn't use it much on data, 3MB fg / 0.3MB bg
Wifi last 30 days: 27MB fg / 23MB bg
Wifi previous 30 days: 35MB fg / 85MB bg
(can post screenshots if needed)

I don't use it that much, usually just to check a few questions on Japanese SE if that matters, they rarely have any images, doesn't seem that demanding.

Comment: Is ... The app polling the inbox to implement its notifications? That would be stupid, and yet it's the exact kind of thing I would do in a userscript if the server offers no better choice. The difference is that I am not concerned about data usage on my desktop.

Comment: Didn't occur to me on Nexus 5, Android 6.1, app v1.0.78 (beta). Usage for 4 days: 3.61 MB foreground, 562 KB background. Could you mention your device model?

Comment: @JanDvorak [SE uses GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) for its push notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221545/technology-used-by-stackexchange-android-app-for-fetching-notifications), so.. no, the app isn't polling the inbox.